# MySQL error messages do not provides useful hints, what about others?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, debugging, error-handling

When you have some syntactical error in a query you will be a error message like:

> *SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'foo' at line 1 */*

Such error message does not provide useful hint to resolve error, e.g. what it expects at that line.

Is there any config to improve the MySQL error reporting?

What about other RDBMS (PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server)?
Do they generate better error messages?

Comment: No, no configuration (I think I tried to find sometime in back). MySQL's parser written in this way... post your query. Only you can learn by experience.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan My question is not about a specific query.

Comment: yes I got your question. It is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL's error messages are generally quite useful.

```
craig=> SELECT abc FROM no_such_table HAVING blah WHERE nonense GARBAGE;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: SELECT abc FROM no_such_table HAVING blah WHERE nonense GARB...
                                                  ^
```

It doesn't say *Syntax error near `WHERE`; HINT: `WHERE` clause may not appear after `HAVING`*... which would be nice, but turns out to be a bit tricky to do with the parser. Nonetheless, it tells you where the error is.

It can often be more specific than this, too, it depends on the nature of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Using *[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33905)* I executed following query on some RDBMS.

```
select foo from
```

Only Oracle 11g returned a smart error message:

```
ORA-00903: invalid table name : select foo from
```

Other error messages:

```
# SQL Server 2008
Incorrect syntax near 'from'.: select foo from

#SQLite
could not prepare statement (1 near "from": syntax error)

#PostgreSQL 9.3
ERROR: syntax error at end of input: select foo from

#MySQL 5.5
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1: select foo from
```